# Add configurable product to existing quote_id programatically

Tags: configurable-product, custom, addtocart, programmatically

Below code helps me to add configurable product to current cart session

```
    $quote_id = '4';
    $params = array(
        'product' => 1,
        'super_attribute' => array(
            132 => 3,
            133 => 8
        ),
        'qty' => 1,
    );
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $product->load(1); 
    $cart->addProduct($product, $params,$quote_id);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

In a similar way i want to add configurable product to my existing **`quote_id 4`**

I've tried

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->load(4);
```

But unfortunately it didn't worked. Any suggestion to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the product to particular quote, you have load a quote with store id.

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // get current store id
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId)->load(4); //4 is your quote id
$params = array(
        'product' => 1,
        'super_attribute' => array(
            132 => 3,
            133 => 8
        ),
        'qty' => 1,
    );
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //your config product is
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($params))->save();
```

Try this code it'll work.

Comment: Not exactly the way but it worked. I'll do the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- `*Use try and catch to exception handling*`
- `**Also use Use proper product model load**`
- Use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` instead of new
  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product()`

As you want to add configuable to quote id =4 then you can try below

Code:

> ```
> $params
> =array('product'=>1,super_attribute=>array('132'=>3,'133'=>8,),qty=>1));
>     try {     $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(4);
>         $product =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
>             ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
>             ->load($productId);;
>         $quote->addProduct($product,new Varien_Object($params));
>
>         $quote->save();
>
>     } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
>             echo 'Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
>         Mage::logException($e);
>
>     } catch (Exception $e) {
>        echo 'Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
>         Mage::logException($e);
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to add a product to existing quote of id 4. Not to current cart session.

Comment: At question.. you mentioned that  current cart session.....Then what would be point of it?

Comment: Read the question again completely. I said the mentioned piece of code is used to add product to current cart session but i need to add the same to my existing quote_id

Comment: are  want to assign the configurable to  quote 4 and then want to assign that code current cart session. Am i right?

Comment: No only to existing quote 4

Comment: what mean there are `no value of current cart session word`.. It make any person confuse..

Comment: Didn't get you. I didn't used such word **no value of current cart session**. I think you still didn't understood the question. Do ready it again plz.